# Разбить массив длинной N на k подмассивов, что бы длина самого короткого и длинного подмассива отличалась на 1

Tags: c#, алгоритм

*Это тест от работодателя, нужно описать алгоритм решения задачи на языке с#. Можно на каком то другом, если будет понятно для шарписта или описаны функции*.
Опишите алгоритм разбиения массива длины **N** на **k** подмассивов так, чтобы размер самого длинного и самого короткого подмассива отличалась не больше чем на **1**.
Может ли **k** быть больше длины **N**?
Чему будут равны длины подмассивов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `Может ли k быть больше длины N?` можно ли три монеты разложить по четырём кошелькам?

Comment: Я думаю можно если массив будет пустой, это на примере если N =1, то разложить можно на [1] и [0] Не могу сообразить как сделать правильный алгоритм расчета массивов при остальных числах

Comment: Ну элементарно же.

Comment: @tym32167, конечно можно.

Comment: О боже, -4 голоса, здесь вопросы даже [типа такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1396352/373567) столько минусов не собирают.

Comment: А что дают минусы ваши?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берете N и делите на k нацело.

```
int a = N / k;
```

получаете минимальную длину подмассива

а остаток от деления

```
int b = N % k;
```

распределяете по одному на каждый из массивов, на сколько хватит, то есть добавляете к `b` массивов единицу к длине.

Вот решение "в лоб", возможно можно как-то покрасивее сделать, но я решил больше 5 минут на написание кода не тратить.

```
static int[][] SplitArray(int[] array, int k)
{
    int index = 0;
    int N = array.Length;
    int a = N / k;
    int b = N % k;
    int[][] result = new int[k][];

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int length = a;
        if (b > 0)
        {
            length++;
            b--;
        }
        result[i] = new int[length];
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = array[index++];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Пример

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[][] result = SplitArray(array, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result[i]));
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1 2
3 4
5
```

> Может ли k быть больше длины N?

Очевидно, нет.

Comment: Опять набежали модеры, минусов понаставили без объяснения причин. Впрочем, ничего нового.

Comment: Вообще спасибо, что помогли разобраться с задачей. Тут даже дело было не в самом решении, а понимании того что от меня хотят. Я пытался сделать так что при любом значении числа K, соблюлось условие, не зависимо от N =\\

Answer (score 0):

Как альтернативный вариант.

Предположу, что не важно как именно распределятся данные, но важно их количество.

Тогда решение можно упростить, хотя идея та же самая

```
int[] split(int N, int k)
{
    int[] ret = new int[k];
    int distract = N / k;
    N = N % k;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        ret[i] = distract;
    
    int index = 0;
    while (N > 0)
    {
        ret[index++] += 1;
        N--;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Плюсы этого алгоритма:

1. не надо перебирать все данные в массиве, да и массива то нет, важно только количество элементов
2. по скорости будет пропорционально K (второй ответ тут пропорционален N)
3. по памяти также пророрционален K (второй ответ тут пропорционален N * k)

проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", split(6, 4)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", split(10, 4)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", split(10, 5)));
```

Результат

```
2, 2, 1, 1
3, 3, 2, 2
2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы подменили исходную задачу на одну из дополнительных. В задании требовалось описать алгоритм разбиения массива И сказать длинны подмассивов. Вы же составили алгоритм ТОЛЬКО расчета длин подмассивов.

Comment: Читаю ваш коммент и не понимаю. Алгоритм у меня расписан в коде, длины он выдаёт как результат - это именно то, что описано в задаче.

Comment: Тогда покажите, пожалуйста, где у Вас массив, который нужно разделить, и где результирующие массивы? (Допускаю, что я чего-то не понял в Вашем коде) В задаче же четко сказано: "Опишите алгоритм разбиения массива длины N на k подмассивов так,...."

Comment: Чтобы описать алгоритм разделения массива длины N нет никакой необходимости иметь массив, можно иметь только его длину. Ведь на выходе алгоритма тоже нужно указать только длины подмассивов, а значит содержимое исходного массива не имеет значения.

Comment: Судя по всему, мы с Вами очень по разному читаем задания. На сколько я могу вспомнить форму постановки учебных задач, на выходе алгоритма должны быть именно части исходного массива, а последние две строки - дополнительные вопросы для размышления, но никак не описание выхода алгоритма.

Comment: На самом деле в нормальной постановке задачи вход и выход должны быть четко определены. Здесь этого нет, но вместо этого просят «алгоритм» и длины массивов, а значит вход и выход можно определить самому. Ведь вам не могут сказать, что вы не то выдаёте на входе или выходе, если требований нет.

Comment: При этом если бы сами данные в массиве были важны - то запросили бы не длины подмассивов, а сами подмассивы. Но этого нет - отсюда мой вывод, что данные массива в этой задаче не важны и не нужны.

Comment: Да, здесь нет нормальной постановки задачи с описанием входа и выхода. Это не вузовского уровня задача и не олимпиадного. Обычная задачка с уроков информатики в школе. И формулировки соответствующие.

Comment: ну вот я как понял, так и решил и не вижу никаких противоречий с задачей